# Downsides of using a CGAffineTransform-ed UITableView

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview

**Disclaimer:** This is more of an opinion based question, with little relevance to any real world projects I have done, or am currently doing. I'd appreciate a canonical answer, as to *why* this approach should not be followed (if it shouldn't, that is)

*What I'm NOT looking for:* "It's wrong" (If it is)

*What I'm looking for:* "Why?"

Lets say I have a single `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it. (Not a `UITableViewController`). Think of it as a Chat-View of sorts.
Now to handle some specific cases of insertion, deletion, updation, and load-more, I decided to rotate the `UITableView`, each `UITableViewCell`, and headers/footers by 180 degrees (upside-down).

Now it helped me tackle most of my issues, and helped in removing many calls like scroll-to-bottom. It works exactly as I desired.

**The real question:** What kind of impact, if any, does it have by flipping the UI elements like this on performance, memory, drawing, etc.

I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: you'd need to profile to see exactly what the difference is in your case, but it'll likely depend more on your code and data management than it will the transforms